# Easiest way to increase UIImageView height?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have 3 images responding to my UIImageView in the main.storyboard and I just want one of my image (`image.image = UIImage(named:"InnieBulb")`) to increase to a height (of maybe 10%{298x330}) while the remaining 2 stays the same. What is the easiest possible way to do it? Thank you in advance for helping me.

```
import UIKit

class CorrectController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scorelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.button1.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(Float(5.0));
        button1.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center;
        let returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userScore")
        scorelabel.text = "Your Score: \(returnValue)/11"
        if (1...3 ~= returnValue) {
            if (returnValue == 1)
            {
                label1.text = "Fin-tastic !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's bubble on", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 2)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Fun !"
                button1.setTitle("Bubbly Bloop", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 3)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Great !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Drift On", for: .normal)
            }
            image.image = UIImage(named:"InnieBubbles")
        }
        else if (4...6 ~= returnValue) {
            if (returnValue == 4)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Sexy !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Swim On", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 5)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Fabulous !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Angle On", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 6)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Creative !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Moove On", for: .normal)
            }
            image.image = UIImage(named:"InnieBulb")
        }
        else if (7...10 ~= returnValue) {
            if (returnValue == 7)
            {
                label1.text = "You're a Genius !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Trail On", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 8)
            {
                label1.text = "You're a Thinker !"
                button1.setTitle("Let's Hook On", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 9)
            {
                label1.text = "Blimey !"
                button1.setTitle("Bloop Bloop", for: .normal)
            }
            else if (returnValue == 10)
            {
                label1.text = "You're Bursting with Solutions !"
                button1.setTitle("Innie, Here We Come!", for: .normal)
            }
            image.image = UIImage(named:"InnieKOI")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line

```
image.image = UIImage(named:"InnieBubbles")
```

add in

```
image.frame.size.height = //your new height here
```

for example

```
image.frame.size.height = image.frame.height * 1.1
```

`image.frame.height` returns a get only value. While `image.frame.size.height` is editable.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `viewDidLoad()`, write these lines:

```
if image.image == UIImage(named: "InnieBulb"){
    var frame = image.frame
    frame.size.height+=10
    image.frame = frame
}
```